# How can I detect if a user is browsing my site from a mobile phone using CSS?

Tags: css, mobile, web, responsive-design

I am designing a website which will allow users to search for an item to display information about it, or select two items using dropdown menus and compare the two.

What I want to do is have two separate style sheets that can be loaded; one for mobile users, and one for all other users. I have tried searching for possible solutions, but none seem to match exactly what I want to do. I'm worried that if I select a stylesheet based on screen resolution for example, users on high end smartphones with 1080p displays will get the desktop version of the site. I want to avoid this by only giving the mobile site to mobile users, regardless of screen resolution. If possible, I would prefer a CSS only solution for all mobile OS's, just in case a user has their JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this

Below is the way to find whether the user on PC or on mobile:

```
<?php

/* Mobile detection */
function is_mobile() {
  $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  return strpos($userAgent, 'mobile');
}

/* Does the UA string indicate this is a mobile? */
if(!is_mobile()){
  $is_mobile = 'its pc';
} else {
  $is_mobile = 'Yes Mobile';
}

  echo '<pre>'; print_r($is_mobile);

?>
```

To overcome the design issue you can use bootstrap

Comment: This works, thank you very much! It's not CSS, but PHP is also acceptable for my needs.

Comment: you are welcome. Just giving you an option in terms of css. Because we are using bootstrap and it gives very convenient way to give mobile friendly site

Answer (score 2):

You can use Media tag in css.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
        div#wrapper {
            width: 400px;
        }

        div#header {
            background-image: url(media-queries-phone.jpg);
            height: 93px;
            position: relative;
        }

        div#header h1 {
            font-size: 140%;
        }

        #content {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #navigation {
            float:none;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
```

Like this, you can define different css according to different screen sizes.

You can get reference from here:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html